# Django/Bootstrap 4: How to align elements inside of multiple parent divs

Tags: python, css, django, bootstrap-4

So I am developing a website and for the life of me I can't figure out how to align the description, price, stock and add cart button in multiple versions of the same `<div>`. I know it is to do with the size of the image I am using but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Here is a diagram of how I want it to look:

[image]

---

But when I apply a `'h-100'` class to the card `<div>` this is what happens:

[image]

I want the images to keep their positions but for the descriptions, add cart button and price/stock to all be horizontally aligned, as well as the height of the overall cards to be the same.

Here is my Django template code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Welcome to MyTea</h4>
        <p>Here we have teas of all varieties from all around the globe</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h4>Categories</h4>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <a href="{% url 'products' %}" class="list-group-item">All Categories</a>
                {% for c in countcat %}
                    <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}" class="list-group-item catheight">{{c.name}}
                        <span class="badge badge-light">{{c.num_products}}</span>
                    </a>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
        {% for product in products %}
        {% if forloop.first %}<div class="row">{% endif %}
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="card border-primary mt-3 h-100">
                        <div class="card-header"><h3>{{product.name}}</h3></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            {% if product.image %}
                            <div class="h">
                                <img src="{{product.image.url}}" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                            <p class="bg-light font-weight-light ">{{product.description}}</p>

                            {% if product.stock > 0 %}
                            <a href="{% url 'add_cart' product.id %}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-2">
                                <p class="m-0">Add to cart</p>
                            </a>
                            {% else %}
                            <a href="#" type="button "class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mb-2">
                                <p class="m-0">Out of stock</p>
                            </a>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <p>Price: &euro;{{product.price}}</p>
                                <p>Stock left: {{product.stock}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: put the h-100 on the column not the card

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed This doesn't work, I already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be corrected with a simple re-alignment of the content inside `.card` and correctly closing `</div>` statements.

1. Remove `{% if forloop.first %}<div class="row">{% endif %}` statement and place `<div class="row">` above the for loop.
2. `Add to cart` and `Out of stock` buttons should be placed inside `.card-footer` and `.card-body` should be closed appropriately. This will leave the image and description within `.card-body`
3. Make sure `h-100` class is added to `.card'.

Might I suggest adding `end of div` comments to all the div statements. The code is readable better in this way and helps in mitigating missing or misplaced `</div>` statements.

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Welcome to MyTea</h4>
        <p>Here we have teas of all varieties from all around the globe</p>
    </div>
    <!-- .jumbotron -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4>Categories</h4>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <a href="{% url 'products' %}" class="list-group-item">All Categories</a> 
          {% for c in countcat %}
              <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}" class="list-group-item catheight">{{c.name}}
                  <span class="badge badge-light">{{c.num_products}}</span>
              </a> 
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- .col-sm-3 -->
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="row">
          {% for product in products %}
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="card border-primary mt-3 h-100">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h3>{{product.name}}</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- .card-header -->
                <div class="card-body">
                  {% if product.image %}
                    <div class="h">
                      <img src="{{product.image.url}}" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <!-- .h -->
                  {% endif %}
                  <p class="bg-light font-weight-light ">{{product.description}}</p>
                </div>
                <!-- .card-body -->
                <div class="card-footer">
                  {% if product.stock > 0 %}
                    <a href="{% url 'add_cart' product.id %}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-2">
                      <p class="m-0">Add to cart</p>
                    </a>
                  {% else %}
                    <a href="#" type="button " class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mb-2">
                      <p class="m-0">Out of stock</p>
                    </a>
                  {% endif %}
                  <p>Price: &euro;{{product.price}}</p>
                  <p>Stock left: {{product.stock}}</p>
                </div>
                <!-- .card-footer -->
              </div>
              <!-- .card -->
            </div>
            <!-- . col-sm-6 -->
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <!-- .row -->
      </div>
      <!-- .col-sm-9 -->
    </div>
    <!-- .row -->
  </div>
  <!-- .container-fluid -->
{% endblock content %}
```